# How to match for a blank line

Tags: perl

I am trying to split the variable based on the blank line. the variable is

```
$s = "iSCSI cred number=0
name=match1
string=2
name=number1

iSCSI cred number=1
name=match2
string=3
name=number2

iSCSI cred number=2
name=match3
string=4
name=number3";
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to it:

```
my @split_values = split/\n\n/, $s
```

Alternatively you can split on multiple whitespace characters with positive lookahead for the string `iSCSI`:

```
my @split_values = split/\s+(?=iSCSI)/, $s;
```

That works for your simple case, no matter if the whitespace characters are line feeds, carriage returns or spaces.

Comment: Its not working. Its giving all the variable in the first index of array

Comment: @Nitesh: Are you using Windows? Try `split/[\r\n]{2}/` instead.

Comment: @Nitesh: I assume you use a Windows editor to write the script though? If `split/[\r\n]{2}/` works, it's because you have some nasty line feeds in your script file. If that doesn't work either, I'd go with `split/[\r\n]\s*[\r\n]/` in case those empty lines aren't quite so empty after all.

Answer (score 3):

If "empty" lines contain somes spaces, you can do:

```
split/\n+\s*\n+/, $s;
```

or, to be unicode compatible:

```
split/\R+\s*\R+/, $s;
```

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of good answers about how to deal with the string that you have. But let's take a punt at guessing which question you should be asking.

How can I read in a file by paragraphs? - which just happens to be a [Frequently Asked Question](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-a-file-by-paragraphs%3f).

If you're reading this data in from a file, then you'd be better off parsing it correctly as you read it in.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

local $/ = '';

while (<DATA>) {
  say "Record number $. is:\n$_";
}

__DATA__
iSCSI cred number=0
name=match1
string=2
name=number1

iSCSI cred number=1
name=match2
string=3
name=number2

iSCSI cred number=2
name=match3
string=4
name=number3
```

This is, of course, just a guess at what you're trying to do. If I'm way off the mark then please ignore me.

Answer (score 2):

Use split with '\n\s' as separator,

```
my  @arr =  split('\n\s',$s);
```

Comment: Thanks its working. But I was trying for split('\n\n',$s); and split('^$',$s); it didnt work. can you explain the reason

Comment: can u explain me what is (?=i).

Comment: @Nitesh you have put both \n & $^ inside single quotes.

Comment: @Praeep: oh sorry typo error. actually i tried split(/\n\n/,$s); and split(/^$/,$s);

Comment: split('\n\n',$s) will work surely.but split('^$',$s) will not work.Because it is used to check the empty line when getting line after line.not with this case.

Comment: @flesh :split/\n(?=i)/ is working . can u explain me what is (?=i).

Comment: @Nitesh: See my revised answer for an explanation.

Comment: @flesk: Thanks flesk. Its really interesting.

Comment: @karthi_ms: first argument of split should be a regex (only one special string is recognised: ' ').

Answer (score 2):

```
my @arr = split(/[\n]{2,}/,$s);
```